# How can I make the shell stay visible in os.system()

Tags: python, shell, operating-system

This code,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E39QL.png
It opens the shell but as I fill the input fields, It closes without showing the output after creating its exe file.
main.py file,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKKTq.png
What can I do so that the shell remains visible after the code is completed?
The answer of a * b is shown so quickly that I can't even see the output and the shell closes.

Comment: it most likely print the output but it is so fast that it close instantly as the program exit with code 0. If you put a `wait(10)` at the end you'll probabily see it

Comment: Yes I know that it is giving the output but the problem is that it is that the command prompt closes so fast that I am not able to see the output. I tried your solution but it is not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please copy paste your code. Do not add screenshot

Comment: You should consider to accept an answer if it helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the Python code exit with code 0 correctly and, consequently, the shell closes.

A solution could be adding a "press any key to exit" command at the end of your code. To do that you can use `readchar` as below. You can put it at the end of your code so when you click something, the shell closes. You also need to isntall it via `pip install readchar`

```
import readchar
print("Press Any Key To Exit")
k = readchar.readchar()
```